# How do I create my GridView like this - text data and image in the same box?

Tags: android, json, gridview

[image: This image]

shows the way i need my gridview to be. I was able to get the image and text data from a JSON and was able to pass the data into a gridview layout. What i want is a gridview like this (Text data and Image in same box) Please help me. I have tried many things but couldn't do yet

My Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/tabDark"



         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theaters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@color/tabDark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your code what you had tried.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a custom layout for each item in your grid view. so create new layout and name it single_item.xml. inside that define your layout for single item and don't forget to give an id to each subitem (image, text)

when you done doing that just use and adapter to put the data inside grid view. You can use plenty of resources available online.

Comment: I already used a adapter and put data into grid view.. But i want my layout like the once in picture

Comment: So you want a custom layout for your items. when you are not defining a custom layout android will use predefined layouts for a grid view. 
But when you do use custom layout for each item. you can make you'r item look like anything you want! achieving layout above is really simple. just create a layout for one item. your adapter will use that layout to create as many as item needed and put it alongside accordingly.

Comment: how to get the image and textview in same box?

Comment: you can get the layout with simple modification to your current layout. give height and width to the relative layout it self. lets say 50 * 60 dp. also define you padding. Then inside relative layout put your image view with is 50 * 50 and below that text view. it should work if not play with it until it does!